# Flow-type Union-type for Module exports

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, flowtype, es6-modules

Is there a Union-type format for module exports... for example:

```
// actionTypes.js
export const CREATE_ACCOUNT = 'CREATE_ACCOUNT'
export const UPDATE_ACCOUNT = 'UPDATE_ACCOUNT'
export const DELETE_ACCOUNT = 'DELETE_ACCOUNT'

// reducer.js
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes.js'

type Action = actionTypes
export default function( state: Object, action: Action){ ... }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do it in the importing file? I usually just create the union type in the module that defines the action types as: `export type ActionTypes = 'blah' | 'foo'``.

Comment: I already have the strings in the `actionTypes.js` file, so thought I could reuse it FTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $Values to convert the values of an object into a Union type. Note however that assigning a string to a const still types that value as a `string`. You will need to type each variable explicitly, or use something like `$ObjMap`.

An example could be something like:

```
// actionTypes.js
export const CREATE_ACCOUNT: 'CREATE_ACCOUNT' = 'CREATE_ACCOUNT'
export const UPDATE_ACCOUNT: 'UPDATE_ACCOUNT' = 'UPDATE_ACCOUNT'
export const DELETE_ACCOUNT: 'DELETE_ACCOUNT' = 'DELETE_ACCOUNT'

// reducer.js
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes.js'

type Action = $Values<typeof actionTypes>;
export default function( state: Object, action: Action){ ... }
```